# Changing the delay of the timer without creating a new one every time the method runs

Tags: java, timer

So basically I have a timer method in my program which uses the integer z as it's parameter as well as the delay for the timer itself. But every time I run this method, it creates a new timer not deleting the old one. So I decided to add an if else block that made it so that it only created a timer on the first time but now it's saying that it might not have been initialized because it was initialized in the if else block. Can someone help me?

```
public void timer(int z) {
    int count = 0;
    Timer tester;
    z = (60000 / z);
    decide = true;
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {noteDecider();}
    };
    if(count == 0) {
        tester = new Timer(z, taskPerformer);
        tester.start();
    }
    else {
        tester.setDelay(z);
        tester.start();
    }
    count++; 
}
```

Comment: there is no reason to try and preserve memory that way in Java, if you really want to I suppose you should define the timer globally, outside of the method.

Comment: How would I initialize this globally? It doesn't recognize the actionListener task performer when I initialize it in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you are concern about optimizing your code you should look into optimizing your Timer class. Like moving the ActionListener object inside Timer itself and more.  All your timer(int z) method is doing is trying to use an object to keep track time not managing the lifecycle of Timer objects.